On Windws, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and every time I install Python, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
On Ubuntu 24.04, Here is the Error I get:
    [I] /home/sporty~> pyenv install 3.12.2
Downloading Python-3.12.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/Python-3.12.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.2...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from homebrew
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sporty/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
Installed Python-3.12.2 to /home/sporty/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2

Is this the error because this is the Linux instance on WSL? or is there a possibility that there is a problem with the dependencies?

this answer recommends installing Python with tk like so sudo apt-get install python3-tk, but YMMV. It could be worth a shot.

You need to install development packages for tk and tcl in order to build Python with tkinter module.
